# Creating test data for calculation using RAND()

Tags: sql-server, recursion, random

I attempted to populate a table with two columns of random `FLOAT`s, but of every row generated was identical.

```
;WITH CTE (x, y) AS (
    SELECT RAND(), RAND()
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT x, y FROM CTE 
)

--INSERT INTO CalculationTestData (x, y)
SELECT TOP 5000000 x, y
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I can accomplish what I need just fine by just not using the `CTE`, but this has peaked my curiosity.

Is there a way to do this quickly?

*I know quickly is a relative term, by it, I mean approximately how quickly it would take to execute the above.*

Comment: Does it need to be a float?

Comment: @orgtigger, Preferably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect other than for the cte to repeat the rows because you're recursion is just selecting them again

```
SELECT RAND(), RAND()       -- SELECT 9 , 10
UNION ALL
SELECT x, y                 -- SELECT 9 , 10
```

what you want to do is more like this

```
SELECT RAND(), RAND()     
UNION ALL
SELECT RAND(), RAND()       -- but the problem is that this 'row' will be duplicated
```

so you need to seed and reseed for each row giving you something like

```
SELECT RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)), 
       RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY))
UNION ALL 
SELECT RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)), 
       RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY))
```

using `NEWID()` as the seed is one way there may well be others that are more efficient etc

Comment: You almost made me slap myself! However, the second row on is identical with this :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of rand(): it will give a random positive whole number on each entry. I had the same issue with rand() recently

```
ABS(Checksum(NewID()))
```

Float:

```
cast(ABS(Checksum(NewID()) ) as float)
```

To be Clear:

```
;WITH CTE (x, y) AS (
    SELECT cast(ABS(Checksum(NewID()) ) as float), cast(ABS(Checksum(NewID()) ) as float)
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT x, y FROM CTE 
)
```

Did not give a random entry on each line?

Comment: I tried this from another SO I found, all rows are still identical though.

Comment: Interesting, we had the same problem inserting rows in a table using a select statement. The NewID() function was the only one that could give a random entry for every inserted row.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this just generates `INT`s casted as floats.  But its much closer than where I was.  Thanks for the effort.  +1